# Executing and 'xor' sumcheck on array of chars

Tags: c, arrays

I've created the array of chars (first line from GPS module) and i want to perfome NMEA sumcheck which is xor of every single character between "$" and "*".

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
int i;
int xor = 0;
int loop;

// $GPGLL,,,,,,V,N*64

char Received[18]= {'$','G','P','G','L','L',',',',',',',',',',',',','V',',','N','*','6','4'};

// display array if needed
//for(loop = 0; loop < 18; loop++)
//   printf("%c ", Received[loop]);

for(int i = 2; i<=14; i++)
    xor ^= Received[i];
    printf("%d ", xor);
return 0;
}
```

Here is demo [DEMO](https://ideone.com/3Sc0JT)

Do you know by any chance why xor sumcheck is different from "64" ?

Comment: You are starting the for loop from `i=2`, to include 'G' it should be `i=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see two problems:

1. the for loop should start from **1**
2. the checksum in in hex ( 0x64 is 100 )

See code bellow:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=14; i++) {
    xor ^= Received[i];
}
printf("%#02x ", xor);
```

EDIT: To verify the checksum you can convert from string to number with *strtol*:

```
int number = (int)strtol(Received+16, NULL, 16);
if (number == xor) { printf("ok "); } else { printf("err "); }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start after "$" then your code should be like below:

```
for(int i = 1; i<=14; i++)
    xor ^= Received[i];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !
Also - do you know by any chance how to merge two elements? i need to perform "if statement" and check if the sumcheck = 64.